# Change wallpaper with service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm trying to use a service installed to run as a specific user (me in this case) to change the wallpaper.

Here is my `Wallpaper` class which has a `SetWallpaper` function:

```
public sealed class Wallpaper
{
   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
   private static extern Int32 SystemParametersInfo(
      UInt32 action, UInt32 uParam, String vParam, UInt32 winIni);

   private static readonly UInt32 SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x14;
   private static readonly UInt32 SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
   private static readonly UInt32 SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

   public static void SetWallpaper(String path)
   {
      System.IO.Stream s = new System.Net.WebClient().OpenRead(path.ToString());
      System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(s);
      string tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "wallpaper.bmp");
      ImgurWallpaperSetter.ImgurWallpaperSetter.log(tempPath);
      img.Save(tempPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
      SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 1, tempPath,
      SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
      int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
      ImgurWallpaperSetter.ImgurWallpaperSetter.log("Last error: " + error);
   }
}
```

It works perfectly when I run `SetWallpaper` from a unit test, but it doesn't work at all when I install the service and start it.

Here is the service start code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {    
   //WallpaperScheduler.ScheduleWallpaperFetch(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute+1);
   //Debugger.Launch();
   Uri imageUrl = WallpaperRetriever.mostPopularImgurWallpaper();
   log(imageUrl.AbsoluteUri);
   Wallpaper.SetWallpaper(imageUrl.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

I've confirmed that it's downloading the image into my temp directory correctly, but it's not setting the wallpaper. It doesn't error out or log anything to the event logs.

Here's my service installed in the local service viewer:

[image: Service installed as the user (me)]

Running it does nothing.

[A similar thread I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092611/how-to-change-the-wallpaper-using-service-c-sharp)

**Edit:**
Added this code to run on my `serviceInstaller_Committed` event which should allow the service to interact with the desktop, but I see a huge delay between the service run and the actual switching of the wallpaper:

```
ConnectionOptions coOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
coOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

ManagementScope mgmtScope = new ManagementScope(@"root\CIMV2", coOptions);
mgmtScope.Connect();

ManagementObject wmiService;
wmiService = new ManagementObject(
   "Win32_Service.Name='" + serviceInstaller1.ServiceName + "'"
);

ManagementBaseObject InParam = wmiService.GetMethodParameters("Change");
InParam["DesktopInteract"] = true;
ManagementBaseObject OutParam = wmiService.InvokeMethod("Change", InParam, null);
```

**Edit2:**
I've updated my service to log to the system events `GetLastError()`. Now I am seeing that the service is throwing error 1459 ("This operation requires an interactive window station."). However, this doesn't explain why my wallpaper does eventually switch (I think usually after waking from sleep). Updated `Wallpaper` class above as well.

**Edit3**
I've confirmed that after sleeping, the new wallpaper is set. Can anyone explain why this is? Could it be that I need to restart for the Interactive Desktop ability to be set?

**Edit4**
What I'm doing is feeling pretty hacky. Would it be better if I had the service do nothing but download wallpapers and potentially had another non-service application for changing the wallpaper if new wallpapers have been downloaded and the user is logged in?

Comment: Is the user running the service previledged to change the wallpaper?
You might wanna add some try catch and see if there is any error thrown.

Comment: I'm running it on my own account just to test the application right now. There is only one account on my computer and it is my administrator account.

Comment: UAC is on I believe, but I am installing the service in an administrative command prompt and the service asks for my credentials so it can act as me. Could UAC block it, even if it runs with my permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of [Session 0 Isolation](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSession0Isolation)? It means that your service is running in a desktop that no user will ever log into, and that restricted environment may very well be affecting your program's behavior.

You say that the code "doesn't error out or log anything to the event logs", but, based on what you have shown, you need to improve the error checking to catch more subtle problems. For example, [SystemParametersInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns FALSE when it fails (and a subsequent call to [GetLastError()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be very informative!) but your code doesn't check for that result. You can not rely on explicit exceptions alone.

Comment: I was not aware of Session 0 isolation, but I had a feeling something like that existed because I had read that services were no longer supposed to be able to interact with the desktop at all. Also, it will definitely help to start logging GetLastError(). I'll let you know if this helps.

Comment: See my last edit. I am getting the error "Requires interactive window station"

Answer (score 1):

Add this class: http://pastebin.com/ERsnqMEy

Use it like this: http://pastebin.com/RYvvT7bH

Works wonders in using WMI impersonating the logged in user from a windows system service. Best of luck.

Comment: Please include linked content (at least most relevant) in the answer itself. Link-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: There are two lines referencing class OneADSysService which does not exist, but all they do is write to a log, so I'm going to comment them out.

Comment: Errors out with this text: "Token cannot be zero."

Answer (score 0):

In Services, go to Properties, and check "Use Local Account" and something like "Allow Using of Desktop". I'm not sure about names, because my Windows is in a different language, but you should be able to find it.

Comment: See my edit. I tried to use that functionality programmatically, but it's not working.